# Iterating through MySQL table and updating

Tags: python, mysql

I have a MySQL table which stores a couple thousands addresses. I need to parse them to geolocation API, get latitude and longitude and then put them back into corresponding address row (I made special columns for that). The question is what is the most efficient way to do it? Currently I am using python with mysql.connector and geopy for geolocations. So there is a simple code I use for geocoding:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT description FROM contacts WHERE kind = 'Home adress'")

    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row is not None:
        geocoded = geolocator.geocode(row, exactly_one=True)
        if geocoded is not None:
            lat = geocoded.latitude
            lon = geocoded.longitude
        row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: Unless the description field is unique you will need the primary key for your table so that you can efficiently update the table. Do you have one?

Comment: Yes, I have key_id column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cursor.executemany()` to update the table in one go. This requires that a list of update parameters be created which can then be passed to `executemany()`. The parameter list can be created from the results of the initial `SELECT` query. In the example below I have assumed that there is some primary key named `key_id` for the `contacts` table:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT key_id, description FROM contacts WHERE kind = 'Home adress'")

update_params = []
for key_id, description in cursor:
    geocoded = geolocator.geocode(description, exactly_one=True)
    if geocoded is not None:
        lat = geocoded.latitude
        lon = geocoded.longitude
        update_params.append((lat, lon, key_id))

c.executemany("update contacts set lat = %s, lon = %s where key_id = %s", update_params)
```

As mentioned above this assumes existence of a primary key. If there is not one and `description` is a unique field in the table then you could use that. Just remove `key_id` from the `SELECT` query, and replace `key_id` with the `description` field for both the `update_params` list and the `update` query.

Comment: Updated to use `key_id` as the primary key column name.

Answer (score 1):

@mhavke, thanks a lot! Just what I needed. Here is a finally working code (I made some adjustments). Also I am aware that using '%s' is unsafe, but this goes for internal use only, so not really worried about it.

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT key_id, description FROM contacts WHERE kind = 'Home address'")
update_params = []
for key_id, description in cursor:
    geocoded = geolocator.geocode(description, exactly_one=True)
    if geocoded is not None:
        lat = geocoded.latitude
        lon = geocoded.longitude
        update_params.append((lat, lon, key_id))

cursor.executemany("update contacts set latitude = %s, longitude = %s where key_id = %s", update_params)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: `%s` is safe in this case - it is not string interpolation, it is a parameterised query. That is the correct placeholder for mysql.connector - my example used `?` because that is used by `sqlite3` which I was testing with. I've updated my answer accordingly.